# Append n copies of an array at the end of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

Let A and B be two `numpy` arrays.

I want to append `n` copies of `B` at the end of `A` :

```
C = [A, B, B, B, ... (n times) ... B, B]
```

How to do this simply/efficiently with `numpy` ?

Something like

```
numpy.append(A, [B * n])        # B * n  is not n copies of B,
                                #      but rather B multiplied by constant n ?
```

or with `numpy.concatenate` ?

Comment: *Remark* : In fact in my code B is a view from A (`B = A[-1000:]` ) but I don't think this will be important here, it should work in a more general case for which B is any array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears you want to use `tile()`

```
C = np.concatenate((A, np.tile(B,n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

First lets check out `concatenate` routines:

```
A = np.arange(1E4)
#Baseline
%timeit np.concatenate((A,A))
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 µs per loop

%timeit np.hstack((A,A))
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.9 µs per loop

%timeit np.append(A,A)
100000 loops, best of 3: 19 µs per loop
```

Note that this is only the case for small arrays, `append`, `hstack`, and `concatenate` should be asymptotically convergent as all of these functions call `concatenate`, the main difference is python overhead. Now the only question is how to create array `B`:

```
#Using python
%timeit np.concatenate((A,[5]*10000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop

#Tile small array
%timeit C = np.concatenate((A, np.tile(np.array(5),1E4)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.1 µs per loop

#Create an array of ones and multiply by a number
%timeit np.concatenate((A,np.ones(1E4)*5))
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.5 µs per loop

#Create empty array and fill from A and then set
%timeit C = np.empty(2E4); C[:10000]=A; C[10000:]=5
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.8 µs per loop
```

Looks like our winner is: create an empty array and then set the elements. This is assuming a certain array size, but most of these should scale similarly.